# std::array copy semantics

Tags: c++, arrays, c++11, copy, copy-constructor

```
#include <array>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

struct SimpleDebugger
{
    SimpleDebugger(int val = 0) : x(val) {
        cout << "created" << endl;
    }

    SimpleDebugger(const SimpleDebugger &that) : x(that.x) {
        cout << "copied" << endl;
    }

    ~SimpleDebugger() {
        cout << "killed!" << endl;
    }

    int getX() const {
        return x;
    }

    void setX(int val) {
        x = val;
    }

private:
    int x;
};

array<SimpleDebugger, 3> getInts(int i)
{
    array<SimpleDebugger, 3> a;
    a[0].setX(i);
    a[1].setX(i + 1);
    a[2].setX(i + 2);
    cout << "closing getInts" << endl;
    return a;
}

SimpleDebugger (*getIntsArray(int i)) [3] {
    typedef SimpleDebugger SimpleDebugger3ElemArray [3];
    SimpleDebugger3ElemArray *sd = new SimpleDebugger3ElemArray[1];
    (*sd)[0].setX(i);
    (*sd)[1].setX(i + 1);
    (*sd)[2].setX(i + 2);
    cout << "closing getIntsArray" << endl;
    return sd;
}

ostream& operator << (ostream& os, const SimpleDebugger &sd) {
    return (cout << sd.getX());
}

int main() {
    auto x = getInts(5);
    cout << "std::array = " << x[0] << x[1] << x[2] << endl;
    auto y = getIntsArray(8);
    cout << "Raw array = " << (*y)[0] << (*y)[1] << (*y)[2] << endl;
    delete [] y;
}
```

**Output**

```
created
created
created
closing getInts
std::array = 567
created
created
created
closing getIntsArray
Raw array = 8910
killed!
killed!
killed!
killed!
killed!
killed!
```

I tried this above program to see how convenient it is to use `std::array` over raw arrays, I know that avoiding old-style arrays is good style and even better is to use `std::vector`.

I'd like to know what happens under the hood in case of `std::array`, when the function `getInts()` returns. In case of the raw arrays, I know that it's a pointer copy and the onus of cleaning it up falls on the callee. In `std::array` this doesn't happen, but how does it internally store the data and how does the copy happen?

Comment: If you are using g++, try the test again with `-fno-elide-constructors` for another possible output.

Comment: @Robᵩ Wow, shows 6 "copied", thanks for the flag!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`std::array` is an aggregate, containing an array as its only data member. Copying or moving one will copy or move each element of the array into the new array.

In your case the copy is being elided when it's returned from the function; under the hood, the array is created in automatic storage in `main`, and the function fills in that array.

Comment: +1 Doesn't this property of `std::array` make it less performant that old-style arrays?

Comment: @legends2k: It's exactly as perfomant as a built-in array for everything a built-in array can do. It's also copyable and movable.

Comment: I think I get it, one would never return a built-in array, or simply one can't rather, and just becasue `std::array` can be returned, returning it would make it less preformant as would be the case with any container type. Am I right in inferring this?

Comment: @legends2k: Do you mean that returning an array is slower than passing a pointer or reference to one in the caller's scope (as one would with a built-in array)? Only if the copy can't be elided; in this case, both should be more-or-less equally fast.

Comment: Yes, I meant the one pointer copy operation vs copying all the elements. Also I tried adding `std::move` at the callee site, still I see the copies being made.

Comment: @legends2k When a C programmer says "return an array", they really mean "return a pointer to the first element of an array".  Built-in arrays have that built-in confusion between array and pointer, but `std::array` does not.  The analogue to `int* results();` would be `std::shared_ptr<std::array<int, N>> results();`.

Comment: @legends2k: I'm confused: according to the output in your question, there are no copies being made, as one would expect since they can be elided; but now you say that you do see copies? `std::move` wouldn't change anything, since all the `int` elements would be moved, and `int` is moved by copying.

Comment: @MikeSeymour The container contains `SimpleDebugger` and not `int`s. But the eliding happens here because of RVO, no?

Comment: Oh my class has no free-store data, and hence no move ctor; so it's pointless to talk about move with respect to this class. Got it.

Comment: @legends2k: Yes, RVO is what some people call copy elision applied to a function return.

Comment: One small confusion I've is that I'm unable to see how `std::move` optimization is the same as RVO; although they both've the same effect, for RVO (or NRVO) construction happens at the callee site, while for the other case, it gets ctor at the caller site, but a move happens after this. Right?

Comment: @aschepler : I think a more direct analogue to `int* results();` would be `std::unique_ptr<int[]> results();`.

Comment: @legends2k: Indeed, move semantics and copy/move elision (or RVO if you prefer) are two different phenomena. Values returned from a function will be moved if possible, so there's no need to use `std::move`; and the compiler should elide the copy/move whenever it can.

Comment: Clarified now, and thanks for replying to all my comments patiently :)