# Return std::array by value

Tags: c++, arrays, c++11

A simple question, but I can't figure out the answer, neither on SO, nor on cppreference.com and similar sites.

Is it legal to return `std::array` by value, like so?

```
std::array<int, 3> f() {
   return std::array<int, 3> {1, 2, 3};
}
```

If it is legal, then it's also legal to pass it to functions by value, right?

Comment: Why would that not be legal? That's one of the core purposes of its introduction.

Comment: Given that std::array is an (template) object with default constructors ....

Comment: Possible duplicate of [std::array copy semantics](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14509184/stdarray-copy-semantics)

Comment: As correctly answered, your first version is fine, but beware: your alternative version is not fine. It will compile, but it returns a reference to a temporary object which immediately gets destroyed.

Comment: @BaummitAugen: the array's copy constructor is not well described in the docs (I didn't read the standard itself, though). I would expect the default constructor of such a type to do shallow copy in the best case, or return a dangling pointer in the worst case, same as with `T[]`.

Comment: @hvd: Thanks. Will it still be invalid if I `return std::move(array<...>(...));` ?

Comment: @VioletGiraffe Yes, you cannot get around the fact that if you construct a temporary object inside the function, it will be destroyed when the function returns at the latest.

Comment: @VioletGiraffe "the array's copy constructor is not well described in the docs" -- That's because it doesn't declare one. It's implicitly created exactly as it's implicitly created for a `struct S { int a[8]; };` declaration of your own.

Comment: @hvd: I see, returning a temporary by reference, either r-value or l-value one, is nonsense, right?

Comment: @VioletGiraffe Pretty much. The only exception is that you may sometimes wish to return a reference to a by-reference parameter passed in, where it can be okay for the parameter to refer to a temporary object.

Comment: @VioletGiraffe But it is. The docs clearly says `std::array` is a [Container](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/Container) and explicitly enumerates the exceptions. It also states that *"This container is an aggregate type with the same semantics as a struct holding a C-style array `T[N]` as its only non-static data member."* Either makes the copy semantics rather clear.

Comment: @VioletGiraffe *I would expect the default constructor of such a type to do shallow copy in the best case, or return a dangling pointer in the worst case* -- Maybe you're not giving the creators of these classes enough credit.  Proper value semantics is expected of every class.  If the copies were "dangerous", the authors would probably have made copying a `delete`d function, so the code would not have compiled.

Comment: @BaummitAugen: I get your point that it gives enough hints, but I didn't know the default constructor for `T[n]` will perform a deep copy. And the first five or seven Google results contained no examples of passing the array by value.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie: Good point.

Comment: "_but I didn't know the default constructor for `T[n]` will perform a deep copy._" How would one perform a shallow copy of `T[n]`? Shallow copy typically just copies over the pointer to the data, without copying over the data. `T[n]`, is not a pointer, however.

Comment: @AlgirdasPreidžius: it's not a pointer, but it decays to one, and has pointer semantics in most cases, same as a C array. It seems that C++ introduced some new features for arrays, but I never had encountered those changes as I keep use of plain arrays to absolute minimum as much as possible. That's why I didn't know aggregates can be copy-constructed properly.

Comment: @VioletGiraffe "_it's not a pointer, but it decays to one_" Arrays are not pointers. Yes, it decays, to a pointer **when passed to functions**. However, when a class member variable is of array type, it, is never a pointer, and it has always behaved like this. Since you stated that you didn't expect that it would perform deep copy, explain how would you expect the shallow copy of `struct Foo {int a[10]; };` be implemented.

Comment: @AlgirdasPreidžius: are there any other contexts, besides the copy constructor of a class with static array member, where deep copy of `T[n]` is performed by the compiler implicitly?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Yes it's legal. It's one of the advantages of using it over a C style array, it doesn't decay. It'll do what you expect it to do, copy the array element wise, in this case it'll just invoke RVO though.

As already said in the comments though, your second version is not safe. It'll construct a temporary and return it by ref, that'll cause you to end up with a dangling r ref.