# How to return array in C++ not a pointer?

Tags: c++, arrays, return

I know how to return a pointer which points to the first element of the array, but my question is how would I return actual array, not a pointer to that array if that is even possible.

Similarly to how would I pass array to a function by reference:

```
void print_arr(int (&arr) [3])
{
    for(size_t i = 0; i < 3; ++i)
        std::cout << arr[i] << ' ';
}
```

I thought something like this:

```
int(&)[3] func(int (&arr) [3])
{
    // some code...
    return arr;
}
```

But it doesn't work. [Here](https://onlinegdb.com/copdH5Qrt) is the code in online compiler.

Comment: Use `std::array` or `std::vector` instead?

Comment: I am aware of them but I was wondering if there is a simpler solution.

Comment: What can possibly be simpler?

Comment: You could also return `decltype(auto)` from your function.

Comment: You could write : `auto get_array() { std::array<int,3> values{1,2,3}; return values; }` 
Do not worry about returning what seems to be a "local" variable. C++ has something called [Copy elission](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_elision)  which means that your array will not be copied when it is returned. So it is a fast solution.
And for your print function : `void print(const std::array<int,3>&> values)` The `&` means a reference (so no copy) and the `const` makes sure you cannot accidentally modify the content of values while printing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot *'return arrays'* directly in C or C++. One way you can use to get around that is declare a `struct`/`union` containing the array.

```
union arrayint3 {
    int i[3];
};
arrayint3 func(int(&arr)[3]) {
    arrayint3 arr = {.i = {1, 2, 3}};
    return arr;
}
```

You can also [return an `std::array`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52328639/16217248).
According to the linked Q&A:

> Is it legal to return `std::array` by value, like so?
>
> ```
> std::array<int, 3> f() {
>     return std::array<int, 3> {1, 2, 3};
> }
> ```

> Yes it's legal.

Comment: I would say forget about your first solution and stick with `std::array`.  In current C++ do NOT use unions : use std::variant. See [P.4 C++ core coding guidlines](https://isocpp.github.io/CppCoreGuidelines/CppCoreGuidelines#p4-ideally-a-program-should-be-statically-type-safe)

Comment: @PepijnKramer Only use the first solution if pure-C compatibility is required.

Comment: I assumed this was a pure C++ question :) But yes union is one of those backward compatibility "left over" thingies.

Comment: @user16217248 What's the benefit of using a union rather than a struct?